# How to use C# interfaces and extension methods in Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, interface, configuration, extension-methods

I am trying to use some C# interfaces and extension methods in Powershell. I have loaded necessary binaries at the beginning of the script and written following piece of code:

```
$environmentsPath = Resolve-Path (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath '..\Deploy.V2\environments')

$configFolder = Join-Path -Path $environmentsPath -ChildPath '.\Stage\configFiles'

$builder = New-Object Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder

[Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder]$interface = ([Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder]$builder)

$interface = [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions]::SetBasePath($interface, $configFolder)
```

I am getting following error while trying to run above code:

> Cannot convert argument "builder", with value: "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder", for "SetBasePath" to type 
>   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder": "Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder" value of type 
>   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder" to type "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder"."

Even though I have tried to convert object to an interface implementation (at line 4 of the above script) I still see in debugger that it has `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder` type and the error occurs. I have tried several ways to cast the object but without a success.

Could someone explain me please how can I pass C# function argument being interface implementation in Powershell?

Comment: Casting to the interface type is unnecessary. Are you using the same exact version of the extension packages? Looks like a strongly-named type mismatch

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you for pointing that out. I will check it tomorrow and let you know :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Assemblies are taken directly from the C# project where those are working correctly. It seems that it is not a problem with assemblies itself.